# Easy way to find out if there is no foreign key link from table A to table B?

Tags: mysql, select, join, foreign-keys

Lets say I have table `A`, with an `id` column, and table B with an `A_id` column. `A_id` is a foreign key of `id`. Now, if I want to get all id's from A of which B has a foreign key link, I can do

```
SELECT id FROM A JOIN B ON id = A_id
```

However, how can I select all id's from A where B *does not* link to? (without selecting all id's and subtracting the above subset from that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  id
FROM    a
WHERE   id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  a_id
        FROM    b
        )
```

This will use an anti-join: for each record from `a`, it will search `b` for the record's `id` (using an index on `b.a_id`) and if none found, return the record.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.id FROM
A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.A_id
WHERE B.A_id IS NULL;
```